# How to populate the spacings between elements of an array with constant step, and combine two such arrays with primary and secondary priorities?

Tags: python, numpy

For a given random array

```
a = np.random.rand(3)
>>> a
array([0.51, 0.19, 0.72])
```

I would like to populate regions between the elements by a constant `step = 0.1`, such that I have the resulting array

```
>>> pop_func(a)
array([0.51, 0.41, 0.31, 0.21, 0.19, 0.29, 0.39, 0.49, 0.59, 0.69, 0.72])
```

Now I have two such arrays (they are the primary and secondary components of a 2dim array); `pri_ara` and `sec_ara`, `ara = np.array([pri_ara, sec_ara]).T`.

I would like the perform the same `pop_func` on each of the axis but with a twist. `ara` would be populated such that down the index of `ara`, `pri_ara` increments to the next element first while `sec_ara` component remains constant, followed by the `sec_ara` increment while `pri_ara` component remains constant, . This is hard to put in words, but as an explicit example, with `step = 0.1`:

```
pri_ara = array([0.51, 0.19, 0.32])
sec_ara = array([0.14, 0.44, 0.48])
ara = np.array([pri_ara, sec_ara]).T

>>> twistpop_func(ara)
np.array([[0.51, 0.14], 
          [0.41, 0.14], 
          [0.31, 0.14], 
          [0.21, 0.14], 
          [0.19, 0.14], 
          [0.19, 0.24], 
          [0.19, 0.34], 
          [0.19, 0.44], 
          [0.29, 0.44], 
          [0.32, 0.44], 
          [0.32, 0.48]])
```

---

What I have tried doing was to create a `np.arange` in each element of each component array, i.e.

```
pri_ara = pri_ara[..., None]
a, b = pri_ara[:-1], pri_ara[1:]
absign = np.nan_to_num((a - b)/np.abs(a - b), nan=1) # nan_to_num necessary to remove nan entries where element of a and b are equal
                                                     # set nan -> 1, so arange will not create any elements inbetween
pri_ara = np.concatenate(
    (a, b, absign * step * np.ones_like(a)), 
    axis = -1
)
pri_ara = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.arange(*x), axis=-1, arr=pri_ara)
```

The last line does not work because the length of the `np.arange` differs for each `x` in the array, and numpy requires axis to be of the same shape.

One solution would be to pad every line to be of the same length, but that complicates things because when I combine the `pri_ara` and `sec_ara` together I would have to remove the padding.

Would really love it if there was a more straight forward method!

Comment: I have to say, you did a really good job putting it into words, despite the difficulty

Comment: BTW, `ara = np.stack((pri, sec), axis=1)` is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! love expanding my numpy vocab

Comment: So numpy.repeat is the trick here. Used over and over and over and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR at the end**

I would start by making an output buffer of the right size using [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), then filling in the ascending/descending portions with a loop.

Let's look at the size of the runs you have and work out the repeat strategy to get them filled in. Given the dataset `ara`

```
0.51 0.14
0.19 0.44
0.32 0.48
```

you want to get

```
0.51 0.14
0.41 0.14  4 = abs(0.19 - 0.51) // step + 1
0.31 0.14
0.21 0.14
---- ----
0.19 0.14
0.19 0.24  3 = abs(0.44 - 0.14) // step + 1
0.19 0.34
---- ----
0.19 0.44  2 = abs(0.32 - 0.19) // step + 1
0.29 0.44
---- ----
0.32 0.44  1 = abs(0.48 - 0.44) // step + 1
---- ----
0.32 0.48  last section is always size 1
```

Using the size information shown above, which is clearly based on `np.diff(ara, axis=0)`, we can first construct an array that looks like this:

```
0.51 0.14
0.51 0.14
0.51 0.14
0.51 0.14
0.19 0.14
0.19 0.14
0.19 0.14
0.19 0.44
0.19 0.44
0.32 0.44
0.32 0.48
```

The trick is to repeat all the elements the required number of times:

```
signs = np.diff(ara, axis=0, append=ara[-1, None]).ravel()[:-1]
d = (np.abs(signs) // step).astype(int) + 1
repeats = np.tile(d, 2)
values = np.repeat(ara.ravel(order='F'), 2)[1:-1]

buffer = np.repeat(values, repeats).reshape(-1, 2, order='F')
```

The remaining portion is to fill in the ranges of ascending/descending numbers. This can easily be done with a `for` loop:

```
ends = np.cumsum(d)
starts = np.zeros_like(end)
starts[1:] = ends[:-1]
for col, start, end in zip(itertools.cycle((0, 1)), starts, ends):
    s = buffer[start, col]
    e = buffer[end, col]
    buffer[start:end, col] = np.arange(s, e, np.copysign(step, e - s))
```

But this is "no fun" because it uses a `for` loop. So let's make a truly vectorized solution. First we need an array of cumulative sums that we can use to add to each ascending/descending section. If we just do `np.arange(buffer.shape[0]) * step`, reset at every section boundary, and get the sign right, we can simply add that to the buffer to get the output. So imagine the following operations:

```
( 0 -  0) * step * sign(0.19 - 0.51)
( 1 -  0) * step * sign(0.19 - 0.51)
( 2 -  0) * step * sign(0.19 - 0.51)
( 3 -  0) * step * sign(0.19 - 0.51)
 --   --
( 4 -  4) * step * sign(0.44 - 0.14)
( 5 -  4) * step * sign(0.44 - 0.14)
( 6 -  4) * step * sign(0.44 - 0.14)
 --   --
( 7 -  7) * step * sign(0.32 - 0.19)
( 8 -  7) * step * sign(0.32 - 0.19)
 --   --
( 9 -  9) * step * sign(0.48 - 0.44)
 --   --
(10 - 10) * step * "Doesn't matter"
```

The first column is an increasing range. The second column is the offset for each section, which looks like the cumulative sum of the section lengths. The signs are already something we've computed.

The whole operation looks like this:

```
numbers = np.arange(buffer.shape[0])
offsets = np.zeros(d.size)
offsets[1:] = np.cumsum(d[:-1])
offsets = np.repeat(offsets, d)
signs = np.repeat(signs, d)

ramps = (numbers - offsets) * np.copysign(step, signs)
```

Before adding this to the output buffer, we have to split this array into two columns, alternating by section. You can do that by duplicating `ramps` to two columns, and setting the unwanted elements to zero:

```
ramps = np.stack((ramps, ramps), axis=1)
mask = np.zeros((d.size, 2))
mask[::2, 0] = mask[1::2, 1] = 1
mask = np.repeat(mask, d, axis=0)

buffer += ramps * mask
```

**TL;DR**

Here is a fully vectorized solution:

```
def twistpop_func(ara):
    signs = np.diff(ara, axis=0, append=ara[-1, None]).ravel()[:-1]

    d = (np.abs(signs) // step).astype(int) + 1

    repeats = np.tile(d, 2)

    values = np.repeat(ara.ravel(order='F'), 2)[1:-1]

    buffer = np.repeat(values, repeats).reshape(-1, 2, order='F')

    numbers = np.arange(buffer.shape[0])

    offsets = np.zeros(d.size)
    offsets[1:] = np.cumsum(d[:-1])
    offsets = np.repeat(offsets, d)

    signs = np.repeat(signs, d)

    ramps = (numbers - offsets) * np.copysign(step, signs)
    ramps = np.stack((ramps, ramps), axis=1)

    mask = np.zeros((d.size, 2))
    mask[::2, 0] = mask[1::2, 1] = 1
    mask = np.repeat(mask, d, axis=0)

    buffer += ramps * mask
    return buffer
```

Comment: Honestly it amazes me how you can come up with such a solution in the first place. It's incredible! I've made some changes to the answer, changing the variable `buffer` to `res`, since it is an in built python class. Also changing the paranthesis of `np.abs` to accomodate for `np.nan` values in `signs`

Comment: @Tian. Honestly, I'm surprised too. I wasn't sure I could at first, hence all the extra steps. The parentheses were placed quite carefully, and I'm not sure how your edit helps with nans, so I'm glad it was rejected by the community. Aside from that, thanks for the interesting question!

Comment: I believe the placement of the paranthesis were necessary because `np.abs` of a `np.nan` would return a very large negative number. But i might be wrong, nonetheless, very glad to have a working solution. I was trying to discretise the steps between the directions for a scanner that had two servos, thus this unsual numpy use case

Comment: @Tian. Including the `//` in the call to `abs` won't give the correct results for negative numbers. However, that's something I'm sure you can solve easily with maybe another step. I'm glad you are doing something interesting with this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not nice but it works:

```py
import numpy as np
pri_ara = np.array([0.51, 0.19, 0.72, 0.21])
sec_ara = np.array([0.14, 0.44, 0.48, 0.81])

def pop_func(arr, step):
    diff = np.diff(arr)
    diff_steps = (diff / step).astype(int)
    diff_abs = np.abs(diff_steps) + 1
    diff_sign = np.sign(diff_steps)
    res = np.hstack([arr[i] + step*diff_sign[i]*np.arange(diff_abs[i])
                     for i in range(len(arr) - 1)])
    res = np.hstack([res, arr[-1:]])
    return res, diff_abs

def twistpop_func(arr1, arr2, step):
    n = len(arr1)
    arr1_pop, d1 = pop_func(arr=arr1, step=step)
    arr2_pop, d2 = pop_func(arr=arr2, step=step)

    org_idx1 = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    org_idx1[1:] = np.cumsum(d1)
    org_idx1[2:] += np.cumsum(d2[1:])

    org_idx2 = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    org_idx2[1:] = np.cumsum(d2)
    org_idx2[1:] += np.cumsum(d1)

    for i in range(n-1):
        arr1_pop = np.insert(arr1_pop, np.full(d2[i], org_idx1[i+1]), arr1[i+1])
        arr2_pop = np.insert(arr2_pop, np.full(d1[i], org_idx2[i]), arr2[i])

    return np.stack((arr1_pop, arr2_pop), axis=1)

res = twistpop_func(arr1=pri_ara, arr2=sec_ara, step=0.1)
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it without the loops. Yours is honestly more aesthetically pleasing than the crap I came up with.